# Why did Tzlofchod's daughters deserve to get a portion?

Tags: parsha-torah-portion, pinchas

Didn't the generation that died in the desert forfeit their portion because they sinned and that's why they died and only the new generation born later inherited the land of Israel?

And even if the daughters get the inheritance it goes under their husbands names, and passes out of their father's family. So what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna Bova Basra 116 B says

בְּנוֹת צְלָפְחָד נָטְלוּ שְׁלֹשָׁה חֲלָקִים בַּנַּחֲלָה. חֵלֶק אֲבִיהֶן שֶׁהָיָה עִם יוֹצְאֵי מִצְרַיִם, וְחֶלְקוֹ עִם אֶחָיו בְּנִכְסֵי חֵפֶר. וְשֶׁהָיָה בְכוֹר

*Zelopchad’s daughters took three portions  inheritance of Eretz Yisrael: Their father’s portion that he received because he was among those who left Egypt; and his portion that he received with his brothers in the property of Chepher, their father; and an additional portion that he received from Chepher because he was a firstborn, and a firstborn takes two portions of inheritance from his father.*

The Gemora then discusses  a three way machlokes about whether Eretz Yisroel was inherited by (1)those who left Mitzrayim or(2)those who entered Eretz Yisroel or (3)a combination of both.
The Gemorah Ibid 117A says that even if Eretz Yisroel was divided and inherited by those who entered Eretz Yisroel it still first  went back to the grandparents who left Mitzraim and was then redivided among those  entered Eretz Yisroel

The Gemorah ibid 118A asks  אֶלָּא לְמַאן דְּאָמַר לְבָאֵי הָאָרֶץ אַמַּאי צָוְוחָן הָא לֵיתֵיהּ דְּלִשְׁקוֹל

*according to the one who says that Eretz Yisrael was divided among those who entered Eretz Yisrael, why did Tzelucohs daughters  cry out in protest, Zelopcehad was not there to take his portion, (so his daughters should have no claim )?*

The Gemora answers  אֶלָּא לַחֲזָרָה וְלִיטּוֹל בְּנִכְסֵי חֵפֶר

They were protesting that had Tzelufchad had a son he would received a portion in Eretz Yisroel that would have been returned to Chefer to be redivided  among his descendants. Tzelufcad would have received a double portion due to being the son of Chefer to pass on to us. So why should we get nothing because our father has no son?

(see the Rashbam on אֶלָּא לַחֲזָרָה וְלִיטּוֹל בְּנִכְסֵי חֵפֶר)

Comment: But if they had a brother the property would go to their brother's family. the daughters would have married their husbands and inherited together with their husbands.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but had they had a brother they would not have been able to complain לָ֣מָּה יִגָּרַ֤ע שֵֽׁם־אָבִ֨ינוּ֙ מִתּ֣וֹךְ מִשְׁפַּחְתּ֔וֹ כִּ֛י אֵ֥ין ל֖וֹ בֵּ֑ן.

Comment: but they answered their own question! They're father didn't have a son so that's that! I guess my question is evolving... But I think you did answer my original question.

Comment: Who is Chefer and how does it fit in here?

Comment: And even if the daughters get the inheritance it goes under their husbands names, and passes out of their father's family. So what's the point?

Comment: @Larry good question. They were all unmarried at the time and we required to marry men in their own tribe to ensure that the tribal territory remained intact

Comment: @larry909 their complaint, as explained by Rashi (based on the Gemara) was that if they are not considered children for inheritance then their mother should be eligible for yibum, and if she's not eligible for yibum since she had children, then they should be considered children to inherit as well. As to the husband getting their inheritance, the tribe later complained about al that to Moshe and the daughters were told to marry only within the tribe (this rule was only in effect to that generation). All this is found in the Gemarah Baba Basra